# How to define type constraint on parameter of method?

Tags: java, type-constraints

I have class `A` and interface `B`, and a method:

```
void foo(A x) {}
```

What I want is to define a constraint on parameter `x` that it must implement interface `B`.

---

Though I know it can be done on runtime, like:

```
void foo(A x) {
    if (!(x instanceof B)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}
```

Or define another class and alter method signature, like:

```
class C extends A implements B {}

void foo(C x) {}
```

I don't accept this solution since In my case I have many subclasses of `A` in a 3rd-party jar and I don't want to modify them.

---

I wonder if it can be achieved on language level, enabling that constraint when I am writing invocation code, on the fly.

Comment: Why can't you change the signature of foo to be like `void foo(B b)`?

Comment: @Sneh In method `foo(A x)`, I want to make sure `x` is `A`&`B`

Comment: I see. @Karol's solution should solve the problem then.

Comment: I am assuming that you cannot modify `A` to implement `B`

Answer (score 3):

If you have to do this you can use generics as explained in [Bounded Type Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) docs, "Multiple Bounds" section:

```
public interface A {}
public interface B {}
public static class C implements A, B {}

public static <T extends A & B> void foo(T type) {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  foo(new A() {}); // compile error
  foo(new B() {}); // compile error
  foo(new C() {});
}
```

Comment: Note however, that when using reflection, the method takes an argument the type of which is only A. At runtime, the parameter is cast to B when needed.